# Output is not properly get as per the query

Tags: sql, oracle

A table name as ***player*** having some columns & data in the table are as follows:

**PID** |   **PNAME** | **CITY** |  **TEAM**    | **SALARY** |  **NO_OF_PENALTIES**

1001     ozil    istanbul    germany     500000  1

1002     messi  madrid  arsenal 500000  2

1003    ronaldo manc    uk  600000  1

1004    puyol   sussex  germany 400000  3

1005    fabregas    manchester  uk  450000  2

1006    costa   ankara  turkey  400000  3

1007    beckham london  uk  600000  2

This is the table.Write a query I want record if team name is "germany" & no_of_penalties=1 then I want to get the record.If team name is "uk" & no_of_penalties=2 then I don't want to get the record.
Mean according to the above records as per the query I want to get the record having pid=1001 & pid=1003.
But when I write the query as shown below:

```
select * from player where (team='germany' and no_of_penalties=1) or not (team='uk' and no_of_penalties=2) and team in ('germany','uk');
```

Then after execute above query the output looks like having pid=1001, 1003, 1004 as shown below
[image]

So could you please solve me the problem?

Comment: accepted where?

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`, `AND`.

Comment: Do you just want to select the records with city DC and flag Y ?

Comment: I want the output like that   CA without flag Y & DC with flag Y

Comment: `select * from table where (city_name='DC' and flag ='Y') or not (city_name='CA' and flag ='Y');`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not actually a "do my homework for me" service. Make an effort, show your work, and someone might help you. Best of luck.

Comment: The question is not clear. Try to post a wider set of data  with an (explained) needed result. Also, it would be nice if you could post what you already tried and the issues with your code

Comment: Finally I solved problem the code is " select * from player where (team='germany' and no_of_penalties=1) or (team='uk' and no_of_penalties!=2);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
SELECT sno,
  city_name,
  DATE,
  CASE
    WHEN city_name = 'CA' and 
    THEN 'N'
    WHEN city_name = 'DC'
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE flag
  END flag
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Finally I solved problem the code is   " select * from player where (team='germany' and no_of_penalties=1) or (team='uk' and no_of_penalties!=2);"

Comment: @MdWasi Good for you.